# Recursive definition of the set of strings over an alphabet

Tags: recursion

The problem is the following:
Write the recursive definition for the set of all Strings Q over the alphabet {a, b} (i.e. the set of strings consisting of a's and b', for example a, baba, abbbabababba...)

I somewhat get the gist of what recursion definitions consist of, but this one has gotten me stumped a little bit, since we didn't really go into much detail about string recursion in my most recent class.

Comment: Hello! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted. You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/), or use the search engine of this site to find similar questions that were already answered. Also, what does this have to do with databases?

Comment: By the way, welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive definition of a string goes roughly as follows.

A string is:

1. The empty string, or
2. $sa$, where $s$ is a string, or
3. $sb$, where $s$ is a string.

Presumably you're supposed to use some specific formalism to express this definition, which you'll have to figure out on your own. One possibility is
$$ Q = \epsilon | Qa | Qb, $$
but this is just a guess.